# How can I use pyperclip on Android app pydriod 3

Tags: android, pyperclip

"Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system" is the error message I keep getting trying to use the pyperclip modules on the app.
Please why is this happening. what can I do.

I have search for the error message, buh the page that hold the solution to my problem is now displaying a 404 error message.